# Continue on the right side when scrollbar is visible

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

In a checkedlistbox control in C# winforms I can add items into it, however the items will be placed under each other even when the height is smaller than the items combined.

My question is;

Can I "split" the checkedlistbox so you can see everything without having to scroll? 
So when the left side is full, it will start on the other half of the checkedlistbox.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [CheckedListBox.MultiColumn property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image: Multi column CheckedListBox]

Comment: I cannot imagine that I really did not knew this before, thanks anyways!

Comment: no problem; the answer is just one google serach away.